# Is there a need to convert True/False to 1/0 for sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have categorical variables that have values True/False in the pandas dataframe. Is it preferable to convert it to 1/0 before using scikit-learn models?

Comment: Are they the boolean singletons `True` and `False`?

Comment: What were your results when you tried it? This is the sort of question that is much easier resolved through experimentation

Comment: Yes True and False

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the data to numerical data either manually using `Pandas` or by using sklearn functions like `LabelBinarizer` or `LabelEncoder`.